# How to map stored procedure in EF 4 manually

Tags: entity-framework

Im working with EF4 and started mapping my classes manually i have a function in the postgres side which receives 3 parameters (all string),and returns me a list,havent found any example how to do so considering the entity frame work 4,any help?